# Searching in ASP Classic

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

anyone please help me to do searching in ASP classic(inventory system)..i newbie in programming and students..below is the screen look like.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/searchc.jpg/

explanation

1. User can input free text in free text field
2. User can select either searching by assetNo/serialNo or select All.
3. User can select all field..

then data will display below with paging..user also can save in excel.

code.

```
<%
Dim adoCon         
Dim rsGuestbook    
Dim strSQL           
Dim lngRecordNo    

lngRecordNo = CLng(Request.QueryString("ID"))
Set rsGuestbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Master WHERE ID=" & lngRecordNo
rsGuestbook.Open strSQL, oConn
%>
```

Database SQL Server

```
table name (tbl_Master)..Attributes (AssetNo,Region,SerialNo,Manufacturer,dateCreate)
```

Thanks you so much

Comment: oh..how to do searching like that..sorry question not clear

Comment: Have you tried using a WHERE clause?

Comment: can you show me how..sorry too noob

Comment: Have a look at some examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187731.aspx . In future, please try google before posting a question.

Comment: i done goggling but problem is i need someone can teach me how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what exactly are you looking for but this might help:

```
<%
Dim adoCon         
Dim rsGuestbook    
Dim strSQL           
Dim lngRecordNo

'Added
Dim query, assetNumber, region

query = Trim(Request("your field name"))
assetNumber = Trim(Request("Asset Number Dropdown Name"))
region = Trim(Request("Region Dropdown Name"))

if query = "" then
query = "%"
End If

if assetNumber = "" then
assetNumber = "%"
End If

if region = "" then
region = "%"
End If

lngRecordNo = CLng(Request.QueryString("ID"))
Set rsGuestbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Master WHERE FREETEXT(*, '"& query &"') AND AssetNo LIKE '"& assetNumber &"' AND Region LIKE = '"&region&"' AND ID = " & lngRecordNo
rsGuestbook.Open strSQL, oConn
%>
```